# Rainwater theorem, convergence of nets, initial topology

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, examples-counterexamples, locally-convex-spaces

I've stumbled upon a result called [Rainwater's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Rainwater) theorem a few times, it seems to be a very useful result in connection with weak convergence in Banach spaces.

> **Rainwater's theorem.** Let $X$ be a Banach space, let $\{x_n\}$ be a bounded sequence in $X$ and $x \in X$. If $f(x_n)\to f(x)$ for every $f\in\operatorname{Ext}(B_{X^*})$, then $x_n \overset{w}\to x$.

The symbol $x_n \overset{w}\to x$ denotes the convergence in [weak topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_topology). 
By $B_{X^*}$ we denote the unit ball of the dual $X^*$ (with respect to the usual [operator norm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_norm)) and $\operatorname{Ext}(B_{X^*})$ is the set of all [extreme points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_point) of this set.

See e.g. Corollary 3.137, [p.140](http://books.google.com/books?id=5BDX2NNsqR4C&pg=PA140) in **Banach Space Theory: The Basis for Linear and Nonlinear Analysis** by Marián Fabian, Petr Habala, Petr Hájek, Vicente Montesinos, Václav Zizler.

In particular, if we apply the above to the space $C(K)$, where $K$ is compact, we get the following result (Corollary 3.138) in the same book.

> **Corollary.** Let $K$ be a compact topological space. Let $\{f_n\}$ be a bounded
>   sequence in $C(K)$ and $f\in C(K)$. Then, if $f_n\to f$ pointwise, we have $f_n \overset{w}\to f$.

---

Weak convergence of a sequence in $X$ means, by definition, that $f(x_n)\to f(x)$ for each $f\in X^*$. Rainwater's theorem essentially says that there is a smaller set of functionals we need to check - namely the set $\operatorname{Ext}(B_{X^*})$. It is quite natural to ask whether the same is true for nets.

> - Let $(x_\sigma)_{\sigma\in\Sigma}$ be a net in a Banach space $X$ and let $x\in X$. Is it true that $x_\sigma \overset{w}\to x$ if and only if $f(x_\sigma)\to f(x)$ for every $f\in\operatorname{Ext}(B_{X^*})$?

The weak topology is precisely the [initial topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_topology) on $X$ w.r.t. all linear continuous functionals. Again, it is natural to ask whether we can replace $X^*$ by a smaller set. In this way we get a reformulation of the above question.

> - Is the weak topology on $X$ the initial topology w.r.t. $\operatorname{Ext}(B_{X^*})$?

If the answer to the above questions is negative, I would like to know whether they hold at least for $C(K)$.

> - If $(f_\sigma)_{\sigma\in\Sigma}$ is a net in $C(K)$ and let $f\in C(K)$. Is it true that $f_\sigma$ converges to $f$ weakly if and only if it converges pointwise?
> - Is the weak topology on $C(K)$ the same as the initial topology w.r.t. the maps $f\mapsto f(x)$ for $x\in K$ (i.e. the evaluations at all points of $K$)?

Comment: Two quick remarks: 1) A nice exposition of Rainwater's theorem is given in Phelps's book *[Lectures on Choquet's theorem](http://books.google.com/books?id=f3po4k5ujbIC)*, Chapter 5 that might also address a few of your other questions. 2) A counterexample to your penultimate question is given at the beginning to [my answer here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/141198/5363) (I give an example of a pointwise convergent net of continuous functions on $[0,1]$ that doesn't converge weakly).

Comment: @t.b. The fact that the sequence from your example does not converge weekly can be seen by using the functional $f\mapsto \int_0^1 f \,d\mu$, if I understand it correctly. That's what you meant, right?

Comment: Yes, precisely. (I'm not sure if this counterexample answers all your questions but it looks like it). Let me know if you want me to expand on it.

Comment: @t.b. You were correct about the missing quantifier. Of course, your counterexample special case is a counterexample for the more general claim, too. Could you please post this as an answer? (The problem does not seem that difficult now that you told me the answer.)

Comment: Sure, I'll do that. I'll take a little time to think about whether I have anything useful to add.

Comment: What is $\mathrm{Ext}(B_{X^*})$ ?

Comment: @Norbert I've added the notation into my post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, none of your questions seems to have a positive answer, even in the most favorable circumstances, as is shown by the following example, given in my answer to [A net version of dominated convergence?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/141198/5363). It is a standard example showing that there's no hope to prove a dominated convergence theorem for nets instead of sequences (I think I learned it from lectures by O.E. Lanford, but I'm not sure).

---

Take $K = [0,1]$ and $X = C(K)$.

Let $\Lambda$ be the set of finite subsets of $[0,1]$, ordered by inclusion, so as to make it a directed set. For every $\lambda \in \Lambda$, choose a function $f_\lambda \colon [0,1] \to [0,1]$ such that $f_\lambda(x) = 1$ for all $x \in \lambda$ and $\int_{0}^1 f_\lambda(t)\,dt \leq \frac{1}{2}$. Observe that the net $(f_{\lambda})_{\lambda \in \Lambda}$ converges pointwise to the constant function $1$. However, $f_\lambda$ does *not* converge weakly to $1$ since by construction $\int (1 - f_\lambda) \geq \frac{1}{2}$ for all $\lambda \in \Lambda$.

---

The original reference for Rainwater's theorem is:

John Rainwater, *[Weak convergence of bounded sequences](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9939-1963-0155171-9)*, Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. **14** (1963), page 999.

whose proof is the same as the one given in chapter 5 of Robert R. Phelps's *[Lectures on Choquet's theorem](http://books.google.com/books?id=f3po4k5ujbIC)*, Springer Lecture Notes in Mathematics 1757. These proofs are based on the Bishop-de Leeuw extension of [Choquet's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choquet_theory) given as Theorem 5.6 in

Errett Bishop, Karel de Leeuw, *[The representations of linear functionals by measures on sets of extreme points](http://www.numdam.org/item?id=AIF_1959__9__305_0)*. Annales de l'institut Fourier, **9** (1959), p. 305–331.

A rather different proof of Rainwater's theorem (or rather a generalization of it) was given by S. Simons in

S. Simons, *[A convergence theorem with boundary,](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1102968569)*  Pacific J. Math. Volume **40**, Number 3 (1972), 703–708.

The Rainwater theorem and some closely related results (all essentially sequential in nature) is also discussed in Diestel's *[Sequences and series in Banach spaces](http://books.google.com/books?id=UVmqAAAAIAAJ)*, Springer GTM 92 (1984), which also gives many further pointers to the literature.

Comment: For background on the pseudonym John Rainwater, see the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Rainwater); Rainwater is also mentioned on the MO thread on [pseudonyms of famous mathematicians](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/45185/pseudonyms-of-famous-mathematicians/45221#45221) (thanks to Martin for those pointers!).

Comment: t.b. I have a follow-up question, but don't spend too much time if you don't see an answer immediately. (I'll try to get back to this later and if I don't come up with some solution I'll post a new question.) The question is: Would the same trick work for every compact space? If we have a compact space $K$ and take the same net as in your example, is there a functional $\varphi\in C(K)^*$ such that $\varphi(f_\lambda)$ does not converge to $\varphi(f)$? If not, is it possible at least for locally compact topological groups?

Comment: And I also wanted to thank you for your answer, which was really helpful. (And also for the wealth of references, although I am not sure how soon I'll get to reading some of them.) I'm glad you're one question closer to the specialist badge for [examples-counterexamples](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/examples-counterexamples/topusers) now. (IIRC to get the bronze badge it is necessary to answer at least 20 questions.)

Comment: I suppose what's needed is along the lines of the following: Let $X$ be a locally compact space and let $\mu$ be a Borel measure on $X$ having the following properties: there is a compact subset $K$ of pos. measure and an open rel. cpt. neighborhood $U$ of $K$ such that every point $x \in U$ has a neighborhood of arbitrarily small positive measure. Take a function $f\colon X \to [0,1]$ which is constant equal to one on $K$ and supported in $U$. Then modifying the example yields a ptw. conv. net in $C_0(X)$ that doesn't converge weakly. This should work on locally compact non-discrete groups.

Comment: Maybe I should have added the following: the pointwise topology on $C(X)$ was investigated in very deep work by A. Bellow (= A. Ionescu Tulcea), Fremlin, Talagrand and others. It quickly leads to set-theoretic problems. See chapters 438, 439, 46x and 536 of volumes 4I, 4II and 5I of Fremlin's [measure theory](http://www.essex.ac.uk/maths/people/fremlin/mt.htm).

Comment: "very deep work of Talagrand" reads like the pleonasm of the century...

Comment: If the above comments are too terse, I can expand on them, let me know if I should do that.