# Simple example on uniformly convex spaces

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence, weak-convergence

In the lectures we showed the following result:

**Theorem:** Let $(E,\|\cdot\|_E)$ be a uniformly convex space. Consider a sequence $\{x_n \}\rvert_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \subset E$ and $x \in E$ such that it converges weakly to $x\in E$ 
$$ x_n\rightharpoonup x ,$$
and the sequence of the norms converges to the norm of $x\in E$, i.e. 
$$\|x_n\|_E \longrightarrow \|x\|_E.$$
Then the sequence $\{x_n \}\rvert_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \subset E$ is strongly convergent $$x_n \longrightarrow x.$$

This means that weak convergence, together with the convergence of the norms imply strong converge in uniformly convex spaces.

**Question:** Could you please provide a counterexample **on a non uniformly convex space** (maybe sequence space of bounded sequences $\ell^\infty$?) where this result does not hold?

Concretely: A sequence on a **non uniformly convex space** such that it is weak convergent, and the sequence of the norms converges, but the sequence itself is not strongly convergent.

I would be grateful to read any possible counterexample. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the sequence
$x_n := (e_1+e_n) \in \ell^\infty$.

Then it can be shown that $e_n\rightharpoonup 0$ [(see here)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1025824/e-n-to-0-weakly-in-l-infty?noredirect=1&lq=1)
which implies $x_n\rightharpoonup e_1$.

It can also be calculated that $x_n\not\to e_1$ in the norm convergence and that
$\|x_n\|\to \|e_1\|=1$.

Comment: Dear Sir. Thanks for your answer. To clarify, you can pick $\varepsilon = \frac{1}{2}$ such that $\| x_n - e_1 \|_{\infty} =  \| e_n \|_{\infty} > \varepsilon$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$. This would show that the convergence does not follow strongly. Correct?

Comment: yes, this is correct.